# how to append new text to div for each click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I have a multi-select check-box option. It is something like with different states drop-down. User can check more than one state. My requirement is when user checks on any check box that selected state name need to show. If he selects Alaska, need to show Alaska and 
if he selects another Alabama need to show both.

But my present code is displaying some thing strange.

**Mycode**

```
<p id="selectedid" class="selected_class"></p>

options.each(function() {
    $("#selectedid").insertAfter($(this).text() + ', ');
});
```

**Another code**

```
options.each(function() {
    $("#selectedid").append($(this).text() + ', ');
});
```

But when I use `$("#selectedid").html($(this).text() + ', ');` always one selected option is displaying, old option replaced by new one. For me it looks when first when user check on Alaska it is displaying Alaska in the `p` tag. Second time if user checks Alabama it is displaying

**Second Result**

```
Alaska , Alaska, Arizona
```

third time if user checks Arkansas it shows

**Third Result**

```
Alabama, Alabama, Arizona, Alabama, Arizona, Arkansas
```

My actual requirement is what ever the option selected by user that needs to be show and if he undoes the check(s) that needs to be hidden. Suppose if he selects 3 states only 3 states need to be display like

```
Alabama
Arizona
Arkansas
```

I am not getting where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Is that java script? if so, `**` is not a valid comment. my eyes are itching when looking at that code.. 0__0

Comment: This is my first question and i am new. You guys nee to suggest formatting.

Comment: @TJ your eyes are now in safety :)

Comment: I am using bootstrap mult select dropdown .In that drop down  each select option contains check box. so user can select multiple checkboxes. Those selected values i am trying to display in this p tag <p id="us1" class="u_element">here selected values need to display</p>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did this help?

http://jsfiddle.net/yq56t8cu/2/

HTML

```
<input name="options" type="checkbox" value="Alabama" checked="checked"/ > Alabama
<input name="options" type="checkbox" value="Arizona" / > Arizona

<p id="selectedid" class="selected_class"></p>
```

JavaScript

```
$("input[name='options']").click(showAll);

function showAll() {
    var options = $("input[name='options']:checked");
    var temp = "";


    options.each(function() {
        temp += $(this).val();
        temp += "<br\>";

    });

    $("#selectedid").html(temp);
}

showAll();
```

Comment: It should be <br/> not <br\>

Answer (score 0):

```
options.each(function() {
if(!$("#selectedid").find($(this)).length)
$("#selectedid").append($(this).text() + '<br/>');
});
```